# Permanently disable auto lock of outside handle

Tags: lock

I have a Falcon door lock and handle. I don't have the exact model but I believe the closest current model is the [MA series](https://us.allegion.com/content/dam/allegion-us-2/web-documents-2/Manual/Falcon_MA_Series_Service_Manual_106694.pdf).

When I turn the deadbolt (part 1 in red), the switch on the door (part 2 in red) flips and locks the outside door handle. How to disable this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, push on (2) with your pinky (probably the bottom; maybe the top) to allow free passage (ie, the outside lever works again).

Comment: That works temporarily until I use the deadbolt again but I want to permanently enable the outside door handle.

Comment: I don't understand: if you lock the door with the deadbolt, the outside handle shouldn't work. Maybe somebody familiar with your specific lock can identify options for you, but all the Baldwin mortise locks I touch work like this, as far as I know.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate -- there can be good reasons for the latchbolt to still be retractable if the deadbolt is thrown, but it's definitely not a conventional mode of operation either

Comment: Is replacing the lockset an option?

Comment: What purpose would it serve to have the outside handle turn when the deadbolt is thrown? You don't want people outside the house to have access to the inside (without a key) if the deadbolt is set, so having them be able to jiggle the handle doesn't seem to be added value to me.

Comment: Also, if you specify the exact model of the lock set, someone might be able to find the instructions for it to see if this is an option, but I just can't imagine why it would be. If it's not a factory option, making it function this way would involve removing the lock set from the door and fiddling with its internals and that may leave you with a completely non-functional lock.

Comment: @FreeMan I posted the photo of the lock. I'm not sure how to read the lock model. I believe the maker is Falcon. Their closest current make is the MA series.

Comment: @cona -- do you have any want or need for single motion egress (i.e. depressing the inside lever automatically unlocks the deadbolt?)

Comment: @cona -- also, do you still want a deadbolt as part of your new mortise set, or are you OK with just having a passage set and a separate deadbolt?

Comment: FYI -- your current lock is a Falcon MA531 or equivalent  (ANSI F12/F20 function)